# How can I swap rows in a filtered datagrid in WPF without affecting the data source?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that is filtered by a combobox and I want to swap rows in this datagrid using *up* and *down* buttons.

I have the following code for *up* button but after swapping rows, the items in the data source of datagrid are changed to match the items that were filtered and other rows are removed as well.

This is my Code :

```
if (Datagrid1.SelectedIndex != -1 && Datagrid1.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
    DataTable dt = ((DataView)Datagrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();
    int index = Datagrid1.SelectedIndex;
    DataRow selectedRow = dt.Rows[index];
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = selectedRow.ItemArray;
    dt.Rows.Remove(selectedRow);
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, index - 1);
    Datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    Datagrid1.SelectedIndex = index - 1;
}
```

How can I change their order without impacting the data source?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to look into a MVVM solution for your project. Using MVVM, such tasks would be much easier.

Comment: @Chrille I am not familiar with MVVM.

Comment: If you have the time and will to learn, try searching for tutorials in this topic. "MVVM WPF"

Comment: Use a DataTable as the ItemsSource of your DataGrid and change the order of the Rows there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code for *up* button and it worked :

```
if (Datagrid1.SelectedIndex != -1 && Datagrid1.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
  int index = Datagrid_PMP.SelectedIndex;
  DataRow downrow = ((DataRowView)(Datagrid1.SelectedItem)).Row;
  DataRow temprow = sourceTable.NewRow();
  temprow.ItemArray = downrow.ItemArray;
  sourceTable.Rows.Remove(downrow);
  Datagrid1.SelectedIndex = index - 1;
  DataRow uprow = ((DataRowView)(Datagrid1.SelectedItem)).Row;
  int i = dset.Tables[2].Rows.IndexOf(uprow);
  sourceTable.Rows.InsertAt(temprow, i);
  Datagrid1.SelectedIndex = index - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in that in the following row you replace your list of items with the current filtered view:

```
Datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

After this, only the items matching your filter will populate the grid.

Comment: I know. But after comment this line swap would not take place.

Comment: You are swapping the items in "dt" which will never be used if this particular row is not executed. I think you have a fundamental issue here, how do you define a swap in a filtered view, what is supposed to happen after the filtering is removed?

Comment: I have a combobox that filled with a column of datagrid itemsSource (source DataTable) and the data grid is filtered by the item that is selected in combobox so the filter result in displaying rows that is related to selected item in combox and the user only should swap rows with the same value in the specified column that is selected in combobox. But after user changes I need all rows for other purposes and saving them.